# Data won't insert into the database after using foreach loops

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I need to insert 2 choices (`$choices`) and 2 categories (`$categories`), which are linked to the question that was last inserted by the `Question_ID`. The question inserts fine. However, the choices and categories don't. The arrays both contain the all the data that is needed. I need each choice to be inserted at the same time as their related category ID as these are needed at another point on the site and each choice must relate to a specific `Category_ID`.

UPDATE - I added an if statement inside the inner foreach loop which will continue the loop if the statement executes and if it doesn't then error will get echoed. The error was echoed. How can I fix this?

PHP Code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'DBConnection.php';

if(isset ($_POST['Question']) && isset($_POST['Category_ID1']) && isset($_POST['Category_ID2']) && isset($_POST['Choice1']) && isset($_POST['Choice2'])) {
//get post variable
$question = $_POST['Question'];
//category array
$categories = array();
$categories[0] = $_POST['Category_ID1'];
$categories[1] = $_POST['Category_ID2'];
//Choices array
$choices = array();
$choices[0] = $_POST['Choice1'];
$choices[1] = $_POST['Choice2'];

//Insert question query
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO Questions (Question) VALUES ('?')");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's',$question_p);
$question_p = $question;
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

$result = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
$id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

if ($result) {
    foreach ($choices as $choice) {
        if ($choice != '') {
            //Choice query
            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                if ($category != '') {
                    $query = "INSERT INTO Choices(Choice, Question_ID, Category_ID) VALUES ('$choice', '$id', '$category')";
                    $results = $conn->query($query);
                    if($results){
                        continue;
                    }else{
                        echo "error";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    echo $conn->error;
}
}else{
echo "Not Set";
}
```

Comment: Echo/log/dump along the route to see where it goes, where it doesn't go. Since you're not using prepared statements (and you really should), echo out your query to see what the queries are. Also check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) after the insert.

Comment: @aynber `var_dump($categories)` and `var_dump($choices)` show that the data is there after the start of both loops

Comment: Did you try echoing/dumping the query? Or add an echo after each line in the loops to make sure it's going to the right places? Have you checked for mysqli errors?

Comment: @aynber I'll do those things too and get back to you

Comment: @aynber Done. the data is there and it goes into the query but it won't go into the DB. The table and column names are correct

Comment: Your code is primed for sql injection (downvote). Start safe coding from the beginning -- suggestion: use PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: @Barns I know, for testing purposes I am keeping it simple then ill use prepared statements

Comment: Why test with a poor code base? Get in the habit of using the safest techniques... My experiences is most people just stop when something works.. so do it right from the beginning.

Comment: @Barns Fair enough. Do you have any suggestions for the problem?

Comment: @Phil135 :: Did you get a chance to try the sample PDO code I provided below?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `else` section to catch potential errors:

```
else
{
    echo $conn->error;
}
```

You should also never use user input directly in an SQL statement. Use prepared statements to secure your site against SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

Use prepared statements and PDO will improve security and make the code more efficient.

So try something like this:

```
//.... 
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];

// connecting to db
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

$sql = "INSERT INTO Questions (Question) VALUES (:question)";

try{
    //prepare your first query
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    //now you can bind your parameters to the query
    $stmt->bindParam(':question', $question, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt->execute();
    $id = $pdo->lastInsertId();

    // check id instead -- result can be true even if the row wasn't inserted
    if ($id > 0) {
        // define your next query only once!
        $query = "INSERT INTO Choices(Choice, Question_ID, Category_ID) VALUES (:choice, :id, :category)";

        //prepare only once!
        $stmtQuery = $pdo->prepare($query);

        //bind only once!
        $stmtQuery->bindParam(':choice', $choice, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtQuery->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT); //assuming id is type int
        $stmtQuery->bindParam(':category', $category, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        foreach ($choices as $choice) {
            if ($choice != '') {
                //Choice query
                foreach ($categories as $category) {
                    if ($category != '') {
                        //execute as often as needed
                        $stmt->execute();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        echo = "no row inserted";
    }
}
catch (PDOException $e){
    echo = "An error occurred." . $e->getMessage();
}
```

**Disclaimer**

I just typed this out in a standard text editor. So I hope I haven't made too many errors, please be vigilant.

**EDIT**

With a dependency insert function (..the need to insert a new row of data ONLY when a prior insert was successful) you should include a "beginTransaction / commit / rollback" strategy that fits best. Using `$pdo->beginTransaction();` at beginning `$pdo->rollback();` were you want to roll back when an error occurs and `$pdo->commit();` where you are ready to make all changes "permanent".

Comment: @Phil135 :: also you might want to do a parameter check at the beginning of your PHP script like `if (isset($_POST['Question']) && 
 isset($_POST['Category_ID1']) && 
 isset($_POST['Category_ID2']) &&` ...